# 403 error / Forbidden when accessing https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profiles.read in python

Tags: python, google-api, google-plus, google-api-python-client

I am getting an "HttpError 403' when I try to access an user profile. I followed the tutorial and setup all the rights in the Central Panel. Here is the code:

```
import httplib2
import pprint

from apiclient.discovery import build

from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 'xxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com'
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = '/xxxx/privatekey.pem'
USER_EMAIL = 'xyz@test.com'

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profiles.read']

def authenticate():
    print "opening the key"
    f = open(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH, 'rb')
    key = f.read()
    f.close()
    print "closing the key"

    credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, key, scope=SCOPES, sub=USER_EMAIL)
    http = httplib2.Http()
    http = credentials.authorize(http)

    print "getting the credentials"
    return build('plusDomains', 'v1', http=http)

print "calling the authentication"
service = authenticate()

print "calling people service"
people_service = service.people()

print "getting the user profile"
people_document = people_service.get(userId='abc@test.com').execute()

print 'ID: %s' % people_document.get('id')
print 'Display name: %s' % people_document.get('displayName')
print 'Image URL: %s' % people_document.get('image').get('url')
print 'Profile URL: %s' % people_document.get('url')
```

Here is the response:

```
calling the authentication
opening the key
closing the key
getting the credentials
calling people service
getting the user profile
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 39, in <module>
    people_document = people_service.get(userId='abc@test.com').execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 132, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apiclient/http.py", line 723, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
apiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/plusDomains/v1/people/abc@test.com?alt=json returned "Forbidden">
```

By the way this is the scopes I have in the Google's CPANEL

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profiles.read

We had this working before, but since a month ago is not working. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Have you tried using an actual I'd instead of an email address? The documentation don't appear to support emails for userId.

Comment: it used to work with the userID=email-address, do you have more information where I can get the ID?

Comment: userId would usually be found by calling people.get with userId=me or via people.list.

Comment: thanks for the tips, was looking at people.list and still require the userId (https://developers.google.com//resources/api-libraries/documentation/plusDomains/v1/python/latest/plusDomains_v1.people.html#list). I need to get using the email address. The project is to get all users under my company domain and create a staff directory with picts.

Comment: You might be better off using the [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users#resource)

Comment: the directory API pull profile thumbnails from Google Chat, and not from Google Plus. Most employees update their G+ pictures but not GChat.