# Google Directory API using Server to Server OAuth 2.0 returning "Not Authorized to access this resource"

Tags: google-api-python-client, google-directory-api, google-oauth

I want to use Server to Server OAuth 2.0 in the Google Directory API to access the user and group information for a whole domain.  For the authentication with SignedJwtAssertionCredentials, I started out with code from [this year-old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19407600/sample-of-server-to-server-authentication-using-oauth-2-0-with-google-apis).  When I run my code I get the following error: `googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?customer=C...3&orderBy=email&alt=json&maxResults=10 returned "Not Authorized to access this resource/api">`

Python code I used:

```
import httplib2

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

# Get the private key from the Google supplied private key file.
f = file("private-key.pem", "rb")
key = f.read()
f.close()

# Create the JWT
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
  "23...fk@developer.gserviceaccount.com", key,
  scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user"
)

# Create an authorized http instance
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

# Create a service call to the directory API
service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', http=http)

# Show the first 10 users
print 'Getting the first 10 users in the domain'
results = service.users().list(customer='C...3', maxResults=10, orderBy='email', 
    viewType='admin_view').execute()
users = results.get('users', [])

if not users:
    print 'No users in the domain.'
else:
    print 'Users:'
    for user in users:
        print '{0} ({1})'.format(user['primaryEmail'], user['name']['fullName'])
```

I created a key, client ID and client email address in the Developer Console and added the client ID and the scopes below to the domain under "Manage API client access" in the admin console. I enabled API access.
Scopes enabled:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user,
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly,
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member,
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member.readonly
```

I successfully used the bottom half of the code to read the users with authentication as an Installed Application instead of Server to Server and that works fine (same customer ID, etc).  Is this supposed to work? Is there anything I am missing?  The only thing I can think of is that the domain I am using for testing is Google Apps Free Edition.

This looks like the same error as [another unresolved question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25857123/403-error-forbidden-when-accessing-https-www-googleapis-com-auth-plus-profil)

Thanks,
-rohan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to impersonate a super admin user in your domain. Try:

```
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
  "23...fk@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
  key,
  scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user",
  sub="admin@domain.com")
```

Comment: What if I am using from `oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials` class than it does not support sub. I am on the same error and added the email like this `delegated_credentials = credentials.create_delegated('tara.gurung@domainname.net')` BUT this didn't help me either. Any solution for such problem